# QT5.3.2 + VTK6.1 C++ program quits randomly after long time running

Tags: c++, qt, vtk

I have a C++ program written together with QT5.3.2 + VTK 6.1. The program compiles fine and can run after deployment. Each function button also works fine.

The problem happens when I run this program for weeks (its a motion control software, so it needs to be on for a long time). Randomly(probably not random at all...) it quits/crashes without a frozen window. In another word, the program window just closes and no error message window appears.

I met the memory leak issue before, the program window first froze and the cursor kept busy status and unresponsive. But this time it just closes itself without any error message or unresponsiveness.. Could this also be a memory leak issue?

So I really appreciate it if someone can give me some hint or direction to troubleshoot this issue by their rich experience in programming.

Since there is a lot of code and I do not know where the problem comes from. I will not post code for now but I am happy to include some key aspects:

1. It uses ADS communication to communicate with hardware drives.
2. Callback function to fetch the monitoring data and display in QT interface, meaning a lot of actions like LineEdit->SetText() are used repeatedly. SetText() is called with a global qapplication pointer *tp->SetText().
3. VTK just displays the 3D data. And I separately tested there is no memory leak.

I am happy to share more information if needed.

Memory leak test.

Comment: You are most likely going to have to use your debugger to track this down. Or perhaps start with a tool like valgrind to look for problems with memory access.

Comment: If you cannot attach a debugger for long periods of time, you can also try configuring windows to automatically take mini (or full) memory dumps if a program crashes. This might give you a clue.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I will keep the results updated.